# the letter L comes out in a weird way in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

currently learning python online and the letter L when typed in lowercase in pycharm comes out in some weird shape I don't even know why; the lower case L is typed 4 times each line which is supposed to represent vertical line of the triangle by it comes out as some kind of wiggle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FdXP.png)

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Better use "*|*" than "*l*" (lower case *el* letter).

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind the squiggle in the lowercase "L" is to differentiate it from the capital "I". They can often look exactly the same.

Comment: so there's nothing wrong with it? Guess I'll just put up with it.

Comment: Nothing wrong, full functional, just a bit of an eyesore at times perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default font.

Take a look at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) :)